# Why TrimEnd() function of C# behaves like following?

Tags: c#, string, trim, texttrimming

A simple code snippet is as follows:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string str = "IsRecorded<code>0</code>";
    str = str.TrimEnd("<code>0</code>".ToCharArray());
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

The output string that I get is `IsRecor`. Why does the `TrimEnd` function strips of `ded` from the string when it is supposed to strip only `<code>0</code>`. Also if I reduce the `str` to `IsRec` then it gives `IsR` as output. Why is this happening?

Comment: Your .ToCharArray specify that you want to delete all content after every char in your string. So d is in your String, so it cut after it.

Comment: If you want the moral equivalent of "cut off this string, but only if it occurs at the end", you could use `Regex.Replace("IsRecorded<code>0</code>", Regex.Escape("<code>0</code>") + "$", "")`. (There are more efficient alternatives, but something something premature optimization.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange TrimEnd behaviour with \ char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700903/strange-trimend-behaviour-with-char)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter for `TrimEnd` specifies the *set of characters* to be trimmed. It's not meant to be a *suffix* to be trimmed.

So you're saying you want to trim any character in the set `{ '<', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e', '>', '0', '/' }`. The letters "ded" are all in that set, so they're being trimmed.

If you want to remove a suffix, don't use `TrimEnd`. Use something like this:

```
public static string RemoveSuffix(string input, string suffix) =>
    input.EndsWith(suffix, StringComparison.Ordinal)
        ? input.Substring(0, input.Length - suffix.Length)
        : input;
```

(The string comparison part is important to avoid "interesting" culture-specific effects in some cases. It basically does the simplest match possible.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.LastIndexOf() & Remove()` to remove string which is at the end

```
string str = "IsRecorded<code>0</code>";
str = str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf("<code>0</code>"));
```

> .LastIndexOf(string param) : This will find index of last occurrence
>   of specified string.
>
> .Remove(int startIndex) : Remove string from given index

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
        string str = "IsRecorded<code>0</code>";
        str = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("<code>0</code>"));
        Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: Note that if "<code>0</code>" occurs more than once in the string, that will remove everything before the *first* of them. That may or may not be what's desired...

Comment: Sure, it's not a final solution, just a simple way to do what he thinked TrimEnd does. Your solution is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be:

```
string str = "IsRecorded<code>0</code>";
str = str.Replace("<code>0</code>", "");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

PS: I know that wont trim just the end part, but if it's not a problem then it could be used